# Compare NSDate to date downloaded from internet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

My iPhone app downloads an exchange rate from a website. It also downloads the time that the rate was last updated in `EST`. In my app, I want to compare that time to the `[NSDate date]`.

Basically, I want to compare the downloaded time to the current EST using `NSTimeInterval` to calculate the difference.

I have looked on this site and read through the docs and am uncertain on how to achieve this. As far as I can understand, `NSDate` is without time zone. It is `GMT`. So I want to convert that to `EST` or convert my date to GMT and compare the two.

This is how I convert my downloaded data to a date:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setHour:hour];
    [dateComps setMinute:minute];
    [dateComps setDay:day];
    [dateComps setMonth:month];
    [dateComps setYear:year];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    self.lastUpdatedExchangeRateDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

I appreciate your input on the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `NSDateComponents`' `timeZone` too:

```
dateComps.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
```

It's important to create the `NSDate` with the correct timezone, because it represents a second in time, and have no awareness of timezones.

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize it would be this simple, but that's all I needed to do was set the time zone on the time I was receiving. Makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Only thing is the method call is [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]; I changed it for you.